# ¿Es posible decorar una función de Python con más de un decorador?

Tags: python

Me ha surgido la siguiente duda y no he sido capaz a resolverla. Quizá no sea posible, e incluso ni tenga sentido, aunque en otros lenguajes sí es posible decorar más de una vez, tipo TypeScript o C#.

Tengo este código:

```py
import numpy as np

def apply_transform(param):
    def wrapper_1(function):
        def wrapper_2(*args, **kwargs):
            if param == 'inv':
                fragments=np.array([w[::-1] for w in args[0].split(' ')])
                return ' '.join(fragments[fragments!=''])
            if param == 'ini':
                return ''.join([w[0] for w in args[0].split(' ')]).upper()
            else:
                return function(*args, **kwargs)    
        return wrapper_2
    return wrapper_1

def upper_case(function):
    def intern_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return args[0].upper()
    return intern_wrapper

# @upper_case
@apply_transform('inv')
def get_string(param):  
    return param


print(get_string('hola mundo'))
```

Básicamente, son dos decoradores, uno de ellos parametrizado y el otro no admite parámetros, sencillamente convierte a mayúsculas(ya sé que hay una función que hace esto, pero es una sencilla prueba).

Mi objetivo era decorar la función `get_string` con ambos decoradores, es decir, por un lado, hacer una transformación de la cadena que le paso por parámetro a la función `get_string` y con un segundo decorador convertir esa cadena en mayúsculas. No funciona, por esa razón comenté el decorador `@upper_case`. Le aplica el primero e ignora el segundo. ¿Sabéis si hay alguna forma de solucionar eso o simplemente no es posible?

Gracias.

Comment: Es perfectamente posible, pero un decorador debería llamar a la función que está decorando, cosa que tu `upper_case()` no hace. Creo que lo que querías poner en su interior era `return function(args[0].upper())`

Comment: Lo que dice @abulafia. Es perfectamente factible anidar decoradores. El problema es que uno de tus decoradores está mal. Prueba cada uno por si solo, y luego intenta anidándolos de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

No deberías tener ningún problema en usar varios decoradores, te adjunto links de referencia:

- [Ejemplo simple](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chain-multiple-decorators-in-python/)
- [Ejemplo Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739665/18953161)
- [Explicacion bastante detallada en Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/18953161)

Un ejemplo de cómo se haría (ver en los comentarios a esta respuesta):

```
def upper_case(func):
    def inner_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        return func(*args,**kwargs).upper()
    return inner_wrapper
```

Comment: Gracias adrigo, ya me queda claro que el problema es mío y no del uso de varios decoradores. Gracias por los ejemplos, son muy aclarativos.

Comment: Una respuesta real incluiría un ejemplo con dos decoradores anidados. Esto es más bien un comentario.

Comment: @CandidMoe, ok disculpa, esque alguna vez he leido que SO te dice que no añadas comentarios con links, por lo que he preferido añadirlo aqui.

Comment: @JoséManuel intento hacer algo como lo tuyo pero simple y te edito la respuesta

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Lo he resuelto así; def upper_case(func):
    def inner_wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        return func(*args,**kwargs).upper()
    return inner_wrapper

Comment: @JoséManuel de acuerdo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda adrigo, fue un error de sintaxis mía. Tus ejemplos me fueron de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Un placer @JoséManuel

Comment: @JoséManuel lo que comentas que resolvió tu problema, debes colocarlo como respuesta, y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Debes redactarla en base a [answer]. La sección de comentarios es para _comentarios_, y como podrás notar, el código es ilegible (peor aún para un lenguaje en donde la identación es crítica).

Comment: Para el autor de la respuesta: efectivamente es una _no-respuesta_. Las explicaciones deben ir en la respuesta, no como enlaces externos. Si los enlaces llegan a caer, la respuesta se convertirá en inválida. La respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el autor de la pregunta, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad que tengan el mismo inconveniente más adelante.

Comment: padaleina, a mí ya me respondió el amigo adrigo. Para mí este asunto está solucionado. Gracias por tu participación.